# The milestones of my pronunciation

Tags: american-english, plural-forms

I write this sentence: The milestones of my pronunciation.
Does it correct?

Comment: Correct for what purpose?

Comment: @Lambie For title of my vlog.

Comment: Ok, well, I shouldn't do this but I cannot help myself: My Pronunciation Milestones Or Tales from the Pronunciation Front

Comment: @Lambie thanks, but what if The Milestone I want to cry?

Comment: @Lambie My question is if there anybody who would talk about article The in front of plural milestoines. I think that it sentence is gramaticaly correct.

Comment: @Lambie copy it in answer that I can close this. Thanks, I just learned something important from you.

Comment: They are going to close the question so it's not worth it. Good luck to you. :)

Comment: @Lambie they are going but they are still not. Copy your tekst because it is awe to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Pronunciation Milestones Or Tales from the Pronunciation Front

Only use The X of Y if it adds flair or "drama"

The Guns of Navarone

[a famous movie]